# How to parser this unicode string list

Tags: python, unicode

I wan to parser this unicode string list into a table:

```
[u'$760,507,625 (USA) (18 November 2010)', u'$760,505,847 (USA) (14 November 2010)', u'$760,462,559 (USA) (7 November 2010)', u'$760,410,799 (USA) (31 October 2010)',
```

So the result I want is:

```
[[760507625, 11, 18, 2010, 'USA'], 
 [760505847, 11, 7, 2010, 'USA'],
  ....
]
```

As you can see, the format will be [money, month, day, year, country]

Maybe you can provide me the tools which can handle this problem.
Am I making me clear? Thanks so much!

Comment: It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am new to Python. So I have no idea what to try this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way I would handle this would be with a regular expression to grab the fields out of each line, then a line or two for each field to convert it to the desired format. This isn’t foolproof—it’ll crash if a line has an entry with a mis-spelled month, for example—but it’s enough for most ad-hoc tasks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re

data = [u'$760,507,625 (USA) (18 November 2010)',
        u'$760,505,847 (USA) (14 November 2010)',
        u'$760,462,559 (USA) (7 November 2010)',
        u'$760,410,799 (USA) (31 October 2010)',
       'blah']

RE_DATA = re.compile(r'^\$([0-9,]+) \(([A-Z]+)\) \(([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+)\)$')

MONTHS = {
    'January': 1,
    'February': 2,
    'March': 3,
    'April': 4,
    'May': 5,
    'June': 6,
    'July': 7,
    'August': 8,
    'September': 9,
    'October': 10,
    'November': 11,
    'December': 12
}

for entry in data:
    match = RE_DATA.match(entry)
    if match is None:
        print 'Error! %r did not match pattern' % entry
        continue

    amount, country, day, month, year = match.groups()
    amount = int(amount.replace(',', ''))
    country = str(country)
    day = int(day)
    month = MONTHS[month]
    year = int(year)

    print [amount, month, day, year, country]
```

Prints:

```
[760507625, 11, 18, 2010, 'USA']
[760505847, 11, 14, 2010, 'USA']
[760462559, 11, 7, 2010, 'USA']
[760410799, 10, 31, 2010, 'USA']
Error! 'blah' did not match pattern
```

Comment: FWIW, easier construction of month name dicts, etc, you can get a list of month names from `calendar.month_name`, it also has a list of weekday names, and both the month and weekday names are available in abbreviated form. You can also get such lists by mucking around with `datetime().strftime()`, but using the calendar module is cleaner, IMHO. (I suppose calendar uses datetime under the hood). Both of those modules are locale-aware, which can be handy.